# Will Ubuntu 12.10 64bit recognize 6gb ram on 2007 macbook pro

Tags: ram, apple, macbook-pro

I have a 2007 Macbook pro running 12.10 64bit. I have read that it would support 6gb of ram even though apple only recommended 4gb at the time. I was wondering if Ubuntu would recognize it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Ubuntu 64 Bit support PAE (Physical Address Extension) so it would recognize it very well.

- Ubuntu 32 Bit Support until 4GB RAM
- Ubuntu 32 Bit + PAE Support until 64GB RAM
- Ubuntu 64 Bit Support 1024 GB Ram

Dont forget to check ur BIOS , Be sure ur Bios configuration is optimal and not limit ur RAM max

Comment: Thanks for the info, ill keep that in mind when I upgrade my Ram